# Elasticsearch distance with nested fields

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a dataset that looks something like this:

```
company: 
  offices[]
```

A company can have many offices. An office has a lat long associated with it. I have a query that returns companies based on a distance search using the offices lat long. So far so good.

What i now want to do is to ONLY return the offices within the company that are within the original distance radius i am looking for.

So if i have result like this:

```
Company: 
  Office[0]: 
    lat: 1
    long: 2
    distance: 10
  Office[1]: 
    lat: 4
    long: 5
    distance: 30
  Office[2]: 
    lat: 7
    long: 8
    distance: 100
```

How can i return the company, but also only the offices that are within distance: 20. In the above example i would expect to only get Company>Office[0]. Office[1] and Office[2] wouldnt be returned.

I know i can do this programatically, but i want to see if i can optimise the query to get the result set i actually want. Vs. all of it and then processing it after.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know what you mean exactly with 'I know i can do this programatically' but by using the **geoDistanceQuery** you are able to optimise your query (however still programatically).

Please find snippet of Java code below. Hopefully this helps, let me know when you would need additional info.

```
    public Set<?> geoDistanceQuery(String index, String nameGeoPointField, double lat, double lon, double distance, EsQuery esQuery) throws IOException {
    Date startDate = new Date();

    Set<Object> objectsWithinDistance = new LinkedHashSet<>();
    SearchSourceBuilder sourceBuilder = new SearchSourceBuilder();

    BoolQueryBuilder boolQuery = getBooleanQueryWithConditions(esQuery);

    QueryBuilder geoDistanceQueryBuilder = QueryBuilders
            .geoDistanceQuery(nameGeoPointField)
            .point(lat, lon)
            .distance(distance, DistanceUnit.KILOMETERS);

    QueryBuilder completeQuery = QueryBuilders.boolQuery().must(boolQuery).filter(geoDistanceQueryBuilder);

    sourceBuilder.query(completeQuery).size(SIZE_ES_QUERY);

    SearchRequest searchRequest = new SearchRequest(index)
            .source(sourceBuilder.sort(SortBuilders.geoDistanceSort(nameGeoPointField, lat, lon)
                    .order(SortOrder.ASC)
                    .unit(DistanceUnit.KILOMETERS)));

    SearchResponse searchResponse = restClient.search(searchRequest, RequestOptions.DEFAULT);

    SearchHits hits = searchResponse.getHits();

    for (SearchHit hit : hits.getHits()) {
        objectsWithinDistance.add(GeoService.getObjectFrom_ES_Hit(hit, nameGeoPointField));
    }

    return timedReturn(LOGGER, new Object() {}.getClass().getEnclosingMethod().getName(), startDate.getTime(), objectsWithinDistance);
}
```

**strong text**